# I want to show the blog posts on home page in hugo using .toml file

Tags: hugo, hugo-content-organization

I am trying to build a blog website using hugo. Everything is going all right on my site except for showing the blog list on the homepage. I want to show all blogs on the homepage but my theme is not doing it automatically. I am using [Mediumish theme](https://github.com/lgaida/mediumish-gohugo-theme). In this theme, if I add any content in the config.toml it will show in the homepage. There are some text contents on the homepage. Now, I want to replace them with blog list. How Can I do that?

Thanks in advance!

N.B: currently the blogs are showing in the cold-email-bootcamp slug - https://splendid-pavlova-fbf620.netlify.app/cold-email-bootcamp/

Code Link: https://github.com/shawon111/hugo-sharable
live website link: https://splendid-pavlova-fbf620.netlify.app/

Comment: Now clue how the theme was set-up, but if you want to show all content on your homepage - ALL CONTENT:, in index.html:
{{ range .Site.Pages }}
{{ .Content }}
{{ end }}
You'll probably want to: 
{{ range .Site.Pages }}
<article>
<h4>{{ .Title }}</h4>
<p>{{ .Summary }}</p>
<a href="{{ .Permalink }}">Read more</a>
</article>
{{ end }}

Comment: No worries Shawon - I made it an answer - accept it below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No clue how the theme was set-up, but if you want to show all content on your homepage

in index.html:

```
{{ range .Site.Pages }} 
{{ .Content }} 
{{ end }}
```

You'll probably want to:

```
{{ range .Site.Pages }} 
<article> 
<h4>{{ .Title }}</h4> 
<p>{{ .Summary }}</p> 
<a href="{{ .Permalink }}">Read more</a> 
</article> 
{{ end }}
```